# Randomly replace 10% of dataframe with NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a randomly generated 10*10 dataset and I need to replace 10% of dataset randomly with NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 10)))
```

Comment: How do you want to put nan's. 10 percent of all cells or 10 percent of all rows having one nan in any of the columns.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following method. I had used this when I was setting up a hackathon and needed to inject missing data for the competition. -

1. You can use `np.random.choice` to create a mask of the same shape as the dataframe. Just make sure to set the percentage of the choice `p` for True and False values where True represents the values that will be replaced by nans.
2. Then simply apply the mask using `df.mask`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

p = 0.1 #percentage missing data required

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,10)))

mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.shape, p=[p,1-p])
new_df = df.mask(mask)
print(new_df)
```

```
      0   1     2   3     4     5     6   7   8     9
0  50.0  87   NaN  14  78.0  44.0  19.0  94  28  28.0
1   NaN  58   3.0  75  90.0   NaN  29.0  11  47   NaN
2  91.0  30  98.0  77   3.0  72.0  74.0  42  69  75.0
3  68.0  92  90.0  90   NaN  60.0  74.0  72  58   NaN
4  39.0  51   NaN  81  67.0  43.0  33.0  37  13  40.0
5  73.0   0  59.0  77   NaN   NaN  21.0  74  55  98.0
6  33.0  64   0.0  59  27.0  32.0  17.0   3  31  43.0
7  75.0  56  21.0   9  81.0  92.0  89.0  82  89   NaN
8  53.0  44  49.0  31  76.0  64.0   NaN  23  37   NaN
9  65.0  15  31.0  21  84.0   7.0  24.0   3  76  34.0
```

---

#### EDIT:

Updated my answer for the exact 10% values that you are looking for. It uses itertools and sample to get a set of indexes to mask, and then sets them to nan values. Should be exact as you expected.

```
from itertools import product
from random import sample

p = 0.1
n = int(df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]*p)          #Calculate count of nans

#Sample exactly n indexes
ids = sample(list(product(range(df.shape[0]), range(df.shape[1]))), n)
idx, idy = list(zip(*ids))

data = df.to_numpy().astype(float)            #Get data as numpy
data[idx, idy]=np.nan                         #Update numpy view with np.nan

#Assign to new dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
print(new_df)
```

```
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0  52.0  50.0  24.0  81.0  10.0   NaN   NaN  75.0  14.0  81.0
1  45.0   3.0  61.0  67.0  93.0   NaN  90.0  34.0  39.0   4.0
2   1.0   NaN   NaN  71.0  57.0  88.0   8.0   9.0  62.0  20.0
3  78.0   3.0  82.0   1.0  75.0  50.0  33.0  66.0  52.0   8.0
4  11.0  46.0  58.0  23.0   NaN  64.0  47.0  27.0   NaN  21.0
5  70.0  35.0  54.0   NaN  70.0  82.0  69.0  94.0  20.0   NaN
6  54.0  84.0  16.0  76.0  77.0  50.0  82.0  31.0   NaN  31.0
7  71.0  79.0  93.0  11.0  46.0  27.0  19.0  84.0  67.0  30.0
8  91.0  85.0  63.0   1.0  91.0  79.0  80.0  14.0  75.0   1.0
9  50.0  34.0   8.0   8.0  10.0  56.0  49.0  45.0  39.0  13.0
```

Comment: thanks for the response but it doesn't mask exact 10% or values. number is random

Comment: Random choice is made from a 10% probability distribution. it won't be exactly 10 %. If you want exactly 10% then you could just run a for loop which is highly inefficient.

Comment: Updated my answer. check the new approach, in  the second section. leaving the first one since it might be useful for others on SO.